# Infopath saveas in sharepoint overwriting

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I need help getting an infopath form to not overwrite existing files going to a sharepoint library.

I have an infopath form with a custom submit.  In the submit I am doing "me.saveas(http:\mysharepointlibrary\FormDropDownValue)

This is working just fine.  But, if I create a new form and pick the same drop down value I can't get the form to *not* overwrite the old one.  I also tried me.save() and me.submit(), both of those bomb.

I have the data connection set up to not allow overwrites, but it doesnt even seem to go into that connection to make the save.  I think because of the custom submit code.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to add something else, a dynamic and unique value as part of your form name. This can be done without custom code, from InfoPath Interface.

Configure new submit option and use a formula to generate form name. In my case I am using the following:

```
concat(YourFieldValue; now())
```

It will concatenate value from your field and current date-time. In case you have some other unique values on your for like username add these to the concatenate function as well.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sharepointusecases.com](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/infopath_submit.png))</sub>

Comment: The value is dynamic based on a drop down list.  But, I only want one occurrence of each item in the drop down list to be saved.  I'd like to throw an edit that says something to the effect of (drop down list item already saved)

Comment: In such case I would recommend submitting your form via custom web service.